# @Autowired não funciona com meu serviço

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Sempre eu executo o metodo que acessa o que está em uma outra classe com o @Autowired ele fica como nulo, segue o codigo a baixo:

```
@Component
public class TokenAuthenticationService {

    @Autowired
    UserRoleServiceSecurity service;
    ...
    void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse response, String username) throws IOException {
        UserRole us = service.buscarPorUsername(username); //Aqui fica nulo e solta um java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        System.out.println(us.getRole());
```

A classe UserRoleServiceSecurity.java:

```
@Service
public class UserRoleServiceSecurity {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    UsuarioRoleRepository usRepository;

    public UserRole buscarPorUsername(String username) {
        return usRepository.buscarUserUsername(username);
    }
}
```

Comment: O UserRoleServiceSecurity está nulo? Qual é o erro exibido? Como está usando o TokenAuthenticationService?

Comment: Quais são os pacotes? Como está configurado o `ComponentScan`?

Comment: Eu naão configurei o ComponentScan, eu utilizo esse UserRoleServiceSecurity em outros locais e dá certo, É o UserRoleServiceSecurity que vem nulo, todos estão no mesmo pacote.

Comment: Qual o erro que aparece? Normalmente quando o spring não consegue inicializar um bean ele lança um erro. O problema pode estar também nos repositories que o serviço depende.

Comment: o erro é esse: 

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.baima.security.TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(TokenAuthenticationService.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.baima.security.JWTLoginFilter.successfulAuthentication(JWTLoginFilter.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework
... Continua porem excede o tamanho maximo

Comment: Como e em qual classe está injetando `TokenAuthenticationService`?

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo observar o @componantScan, coloque como basePackage de atributo o caminho dos seus pacotes. Também, recomendo anotar essa sua classe de service com a anotação @Service